# What would setting a getter do?

Tags: objective-c, syntax, setter, getter

First, some context:  while answering questions on SO, I came across a post wherein the author had been trying to set a getter with syntax similar to `[self.propertyGetter:newValue];`.  For some reason, this compiles, and I thought to myself, "this would constitute a call to nil, wouldn't it?". So, my question is, why in the heck does this 'work'?  (to be perfectly clear, the poster was complaining that this had no effect, so by 'work', I mean compile).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you quoted is `[self.propertyGetter:newValue]`.  Here's how the Objective-C compiler parses this.

The first thing after the left bracket has to be the receiver of the message.  In that code, the receiver is the value of `self.propertyGetter`.  The compiler transforms `self.propertyGetter` into `[self propertyGetter]`.  So we can rewrite the code you quoted as `[[self propertyGetter]:newValue]`.

Now the compiler needs to figure out the selector of the message.  You usually see a keyword selector like `setStatusBarHidden:animated:`, which is a series of keywords followed by colons.  But it turns out a keyword can be zero-length.  So a colon by itself is a valid keyword selector.  So the compiler sees it like this: `[[self propertyGetter] :newValue]`.  (Using a zero-length keyword is almost always very bad style.)

You can declare an instance method using that selector.  For example:

```
- (void):(NSObject *)newValue;
```

If `[self propertyGetter]` returns an object of a class that has that method, the code will compile and run.

If the compiler has seen *any* class with a method named like that, and `[self propertyGetter]` returns type `id`, then the code will compile (because `id` is a wildcard type and the compiler will not complain if you try to send it *any* known message selector).  However, the app will crash at runtime if `[self propertyGetter]` doesn't actually understand the `:` message.

Comment: In this case, it was the UILabel `backgroundColor` property he had tried to set.  I guess he got lucky.  As always, your superior answers are much appreciated Rob.

Comment: I'd like to see a compiling example of that... not that I don't believe the answer, but because syntax ambiguity around `[]` was always.... interesting.

Answer (score 1):

This compiles because all objective-C objects are dynamic entities by default. It would compile, but would crash at runtime.

[Source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocStaticBehavior.html).

Comment: The thing is, it didn't crash for him, it simply has no effect.

Comment: As you mentioned, messages sent to nil produce nil and that is ok in objective-c.

Comment: So, I was right, setting a getter is a call to nil?  Thanks.  I will accept when the time limit is over.